# How to effectively close a page?

Tags: seo

Before asking my question, I'll use an example to clarify the idea.

Say that a company used to sell horses and then they turn into a sheeps business. While some of the old pages can be mapped to the new pages using a 301 redirect, because they're really related in the content and the company don't want to lose users and link juice, there are a lot of pages strictly related to horses that they want to shutdown.

What's the best practice? Is there a way to say to users and Search Engines the content you were looking for won't be available any more?

Basically a 301 redirect of the closed pages to new ones seems not so good, because you'll show a content totally unrelated to the searched one.

P.S: I'm aware that probably the best fallback is to simply map those pages to the homepage but I hope in a smarter solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Best pratices is to return 410 HTTP response code for these webpages.

> **410 Gone**
>
> Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available
> and will not be available again. This should be used when a
> resource has been intentionally removed and the resource should be
> purged. Upon receiving a 410 status code, the client should not
> request the resource again in the future. Clients such as search
> engines should remove the resource from their indices. Most use cases
> do not require clients and search engines to purge the resource, and a
> "404 Not Found" may be used instead.

([Wikipedia source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes))