# Google Search for my domain has about 3500 3-rd level subdomain I did not create

Tags: google-search, links, google-index

Some time ago I created the domain in `.com` zone. Now I tried to evaluate the number of pages are in Google index using request like `site:mydomain.com` but surprisingly there were a lot of results like:

> Pools Above Ground Store poolsabovegroundstore.mydomain.com/‎ Intex
>   15-Foot-by-42-Inch Family Size Round Metal Frame Pool Set Intex
>   56948EB. Intex 15-Foot-by-42-Inch Family Size Round Metal Frame Pool
>   Set.

All those links are not working giving 404 error.

This domain hosted on Hostgator shared hosting. Do you have any ideas how does all of those pages appeared in Google index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Google indexed those links, this is because they existed in the past. Googlebot found them by following existing links on another page (internal or external).

If you don't want to see those links  in Google index, you can return a 410 HTTP status by using an *.htaccess* file for example (if you use Apache as a web server). See [this topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50666/how-to-effectively-close-a-page/) for this.

Just for information, your web host has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Good guess, @Zistoloen! Am I able to track the domain history?

Comment: and should I care about those non existing pages in Google?

Comment: It's not important to pay attention to the history of 404 pages, you just need to fix all links on your site which lead to 404 pages. Scan your site with [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to find those links. If you don't find links pointing to URLs listed in Google, use 410 HTTP status for those URLs with a *.htaccess* file.